# Why is it not possible to publish my Azure Dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I am trying to publish my Azure Dashboard by using the share button above in the Azure Portal:

[image]

Then I fill out the form with the needed data:

[image]

When I submit it I receive the following error:

[image]

Does anybody know why this is failing with the error "Cannot read property 'position' of null"? What can I do about it to fix it?

Edit:

It happens with every Dashboard, one of them looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your dashboard?

Comment: Yes. I Have added a screenshot in the question. Basically it happens with every Dashboard I try. Also with the default Dashboard.

Comment: Hmm, for me it works fine. maybe the property value is fetched from the client browser (possibly?). which browser do you use? did you try with other browsers?

Comment: Or, modify some tiles and save in order to refresh every tile properties forcefully.

Comment: I tried with latest Chrome and IE 11. Which browser did you use?

Comment: I'm using Chrome in Windows 10.

Comment: I am only able to publish a new empty Dashboard, otherwise it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to create a new empty dashboard, publish it and add the needed items.

Answer (score 0):

Start moving your tiles. You may find one (or more) broken tiles somewhere in your dashboard. My reasoning is, that when a tile extends outside of the dashboard, its x or y coordinates become null which isn't properly handled in the code.

Delete the broken tile and you should be good to go. Happened to me once.

[image: Broken Tile]